# Count vowels, consonsants, digits, and other char in a entered string of text (language c#)

Tags: c#, char

Can someone please look at my code?  I need to count the characters from the entered textbox and have them display in the correct label box. (consonant, vowel, digit and other)  I did have the digit one working and them messed it up working on the vowels.

// determines if the text is a consonant, vowel, digit or other character.  Then it displays the count of each.

```
int consCount = 0;
int vowelCount = 0;
int digitCount = 0;
int otherCount = 0;

string inputString;   
inputString = this.entryTextBox.Text.ToLower();


char[] vowels = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
string vow = new string(vowels);

for (int index = 0; index < inputString.Length; index++)
{

    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(inputString[index]))
    {
        if (inputString.Contains(vow))
                vowelCount++;
    }

    else if (char.IsDigit(inputString[index]))
       digitCount++;

}
this.voweldisplayLabel.Text = vowelCount.ToString();
this.digitsdisplayLabel.Text = digitCount.ToString();
this.constdisplayLabel.Text = consCount.ToString();
this.otherdisplayLabel.Text = otherCount.ToString();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does the code do and what do you expect it to do? And I think an example would help too.

Comment: I updated the question.  I have to determine if the text from the textbox is a consonant, vowel, digit or other character. Then it displays the count of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code you posted:

1. The placement of the `else` lines up with the `for` and not the `if`, as it should.
2. `String.Contains` is trying to match up the *entire char set*...it is not picking it apart and looking for every character individually (it will only be `true` when the string contains `aeiou` as a chunk).  You could use Linq to accomplish this as a one-liner if you'd like.  Otherwise, nest a `foreach` and loop across the `char` list to find your match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up with the else statement. It should be directly after the closing bracket of the if statement. But here it's behind the closing bracket of the for loop. Maybe you need some sleep ;)

Comment: I believe I have fixed what you were talking about, but I still can't see what I have done wrong.  I don't have syntax errors, I know its my logic - I just can't figure out what it is.   Any suggestions.. I'm Not looked for anyone do the work from, I just need a push it the right direction to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I got both the vowels and digits to display properly.  =)  Now I am off to work on the consonants and other characters.

```
        int vowelCount = 0;
        int digitCount = 0;

        string inputString;
        inputString = this.entryTextBox.Text.ToLower();

        char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        string vow = new string(vowels);

        for (int index = 0; index < inputString.Length; index++)
        {

            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(inputString[index]))
            {
                if (vow.Contains(inputString[index]))
                {
                    vowelCount++;
                }

            else if (char.IsDigit(inputString[index]))
                digitCount++;

            }

        }
        this.voweldisplayLabel.Text = vowelCount.ToString();
        this.digitsdisplayLabel.Text = digitCount.ToString();
```